# JSF 2 - Ajax Property not found

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I got this error:

```
execute="#{localeManager.changeLocale}": Property 'changeLocale' not found on type xyz.com.i18n.LocaleManager
```

where LocaleManager is:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class LocaleManager implements Serializable
{
    // other codes here

    public static void changeLocale(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
       newLocale = (Locale) new Locale((String) event.toString());
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("selectedLocale", newLocale); 
    }
}
```

and I'm calling the bean's method here:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectLang" immediate="true" value="#{langListing.language}">
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="#{localeManager.changeLocale}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{langListing.languages}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I'm learning AJAX by experimenting with this code. But I don't understand how Ajax evaluates bean's method. Is this a straightforward issue to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`<f:ajax>` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) the `execute` attribute should refer to a collection of client IDs which are to be processed at the server side. This should not refer to some bean action method. The exception is coming because it's expecting a **getter** method which returns a collection of client IDs.

You want to use the `listener` attribute instead.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{localeManager.changeLocale}" />
```

Note that the default event for `h:selectOneMenu` is already `valueChange`. You can just omit it.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. Is there a way to get the selected value from h:selectOneMenu? event.toString() only returns the event. I have looked through the content assist in Eclipse but couldn't find a method to return the value selected in h:selectOneMenu.

Comment: Just access property behind value `#{langListing.language}`. Since it's apparently on a different managed bean, you'd like to refactor one and other e.g. change to `#{localeManager.language}` or inject one in other e.g. `@ManagedProperty(value="#{langListing}) private LangListing langListing;` inside `LocaleManager`.

Comment: I haven't done JSF 2 injection but your example works great. I have another question but I want to figure it out for myself first before I come here to ask a question. Anyway, thanks heap and cheers.